# missing field level constraints, field level permission in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

Field level constraints, field level permission are missing from sharepoint online. is it by design or was it moved somewhere else?

Comment: It is by designed. In SharePoint Field level security is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

In Sharepoint field level constrain is not possible out of the box. This is Design limitation. There was one codeplex solution for on premise (but it was more smoke and mirrors than real filed level security)